# Variables initialization error

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Table with 4 cells (thumbnails to be displayed from an URI).
If the URI is empty, I want to display a placeholder image.
If not empty, I want to display an activity indicator while downloading.

What I have is a very "quick and dirty" code - but it works:

```
func setCell(previewView1: String,  previewView2: String, previewView3: String, previewView4: String, id: String) {
    self.loadPreview1(previewView1)
    self.loadPreview2(previewView2)
    self.loadPreview3(previewView3)
    self.loadPreview4(previewView4)
    self.cellID = id;
}

func loadPreview1(urlString: String) {
    if urlString == "" {
        self.previewView1.image = UIImage(named: "imagePlatzhalter")
        self.activityIndicator1.stopAnimating(); // Animation stoppen
    }
    else {
        self.activityIndicator1.startAnimating() // Animation Start
        var imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString);
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!);
        let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue();
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                // Update the cell
                self.activityIndicator1.stopAnimating(); // Animation stoppen
                self.previewView1.image = image;
            }
            else {
                println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.previewView1.image = UIImage(named: "imagePlatzhalter")
                self.activityIndicator1.stopAnimating(); // Animation stoppen
            }
        })
    }
}

func loadPreview2(urlString: String) {
    if urlString == "" {
        self.previewView2.image = UIImage(named: "imagePlatzhalter")
        self.activityIndicator2.stopAnimating(); // Animation stoppen
    }
    else {
        self.activityIndicator2.startAnimating() // Animation Start
        var imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString);
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!);
        let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue();
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                // Update the cell
                self.activityIndicator2.stopAnimating(); // Animation stoppen
                self.previewView2.image = image;
            }
            else {
                println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.previewView2.image = UIImage(named: "imagePlatzhalter")
                self.activityIndicator2.stopAnimating(); // Animation stoppen
            }
        })
    }
}
func loadPreview3(urlString: String) {
: same as 1 and 2 with references on self.previewView3 and self.activityIndicator3...
}

func loadPreview4(urlString: String) {
: same as 1 and 2 with references on self.previewView4 and self.activityIndicator4...
}
```

This solution works fine, but I want to refactor now the code in a nicer solution. This is my approach:

```
func previewImage (urlString: String, controlIndex: Int) {
    var previewViewImage : UIImage;
    var activityIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView;

    if controlIndex == 1 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView1.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator1;
    } else if controlIndex == 2 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView2.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator2;
    } else if controlIndex == 3 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView3.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator3;
    } else if controlIndex == 4 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView4.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator4;
    }

    if urlString == "" {
        // Set image to placeholder image:
        previewViewImage = UIImage(named: "imagePlatzhalter")!;
    }
    else {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating() // Animation Start
        var imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString);

        // Check ob Image gecacht ist / TODO
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL!);
        let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue();
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                // Store the image in to our cache
                //self.imageCache[urlString] = image

                // Update the cell
                previewViewImage = image!;
            }
            else {
                println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                previewViewImage = UIImage(named: "imagePlatzhalter")!;
            }
        })

    }
    // Stop activity indicator:
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
}
```

But Xcode throws here 3 errors:

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

> Error: "Variable activityIndicator used before initialized

Same on

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
```

And within the callback I got the error:

> "Variable previewViewImage captured by a closure before being
>   initialized"

I'm new to Swift and don't understand, why my code won't work. Can anyone help me to refactor the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift sees a possible path in which `previewViewImage` and `activityIndicator` are not initialized.  Here is your code:

```
func previewImage (urlString: String, controlIndex: Int) {
    var previewViewImage : UIImage;
    var activityIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView;

    if controlIndex == 1 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView1.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator1;
    } else if controlIndex == 2 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView2.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator2;
    } else if controlIndex == 3 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView3.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator3;
    } else if controlIndex == 4 {
        previewViewImage = self.previewView4.image!;
        activityIndicator = self.activityIndicator4;
    }
```

What would happen if `controlIndex` were `5`?  Neither variable would be initialized.  So, Swift treats them as possibly uninitialized, which is why you are getting the errors.

You can fix this by making the last `else if` simply an `else`.  In that case, you'd want to `assert` that `controlIndex == 4`.  Or, you could initialize `previewViewImage` and `activityIndicator` to some reasonable default values before the `if`.

Comment: Damn thanks a lot. Changed last else if to if works like a charm. Don´t know till now, that Xcode/Swift is so strict...

Comment: Swift is just doing you a favor. It is eliminating the possibility of hard to find bugs by insisting that you have initialized your variables properly.

Comment: It is Swift style to leave off the semicolons at the ends of lines.